# Internet explorer 11 javascript : Object are static

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Using the interactive console in IE11 (F12), I have static object

```
user=> a={a:5,b:6}
  [object Object] { a : 5 , b : 6 }
user=> a.l=6
  object does not support this property
```

The first line of the Console says :

```
The attached page targets document mode 5. Some console APIs and features may not be available.
```

Yes, indeed, some API are not accessible!

How can I get dynamic object with javascript in IE11?

Comment: I just checked in IE11 and that code works fine, though I'm not sure what this `user=>` part is supposed to be, I just did the `a=` part which assigns `a` to `window`

Comment: This seems to work as expected for me in IE 11.

Comment: It seem to depend upon the document loaded in IE11.

Comment: Please provide the conditions it doesn't work in, not sure what you mean by what type of document

Comment: Here I edit, I found a "attached document is in mode 5.  Some API could not be accessible."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the document was a document in a frame windows.

So, I added the following line in the `header`of the html document that countains the `frameset` tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
```

Then the message did not appears again.  It seems that the problem was solved and that attribute can be added dynamically as in the w3c norm.

Answer (score 1):

You've set your document mode to 5 (Internet Explorer 5), change it back to 11:

[image]

Comment: I working in a big company, so informatician are always more knowledgeable than others...